# Proof if their is a defined X.

Tags: linear-algebra

I seem to have some problems with this one. Maybe you can check if i did it right.

Let Y ∈ N with Y ≥ 2. Show that their exist one definite X ∈ N with X + 2 = Y

Solution: I did it by a contradiction proof, by saying there is not a definite X so that
 X, X' are elements of N with X not the same as X'. And as we know should X+2 = X'+2 = y. However this can not be true, as also Y-2 = X = X' as we defined X is not the same as X'

Is this enough or does it make no sense.

Comment: What is your definition of $N$?

Comment: Sorry should be the Natural numbers

Comment: why don't you take $X=Y-2$.

Comment: Well i thought of that too but wasnt sure if that's enough for a mathematical proof

Comment: what you have done could be useful to prove the unicity of such $X$.

Comment: Hmm I see .. Well i have no clue how else i could show it